# How to use C99 standard types for maximum portability AND efficiency across most platforms?

Tags: c, performance, optimization, types, c99

First, here is what I understand and think what is true for the question.

1. Use fast data types for single variables like counters or `for` loop indexes. For example:

   ```
   #define LOOP_COUNT (100U)

   uint_fast8_t index;
   for(index = 0; index < LOOP_COUNT; index++){
       /* Do something */
   }
   ```

   I suppose the most suitable type in here is `uint_fast8_t` since `index` can never exceed 255 and this will be the fastest implementation for all platforms. If I used `unsigned int` instead, it will be fastest in >=16 bits platforms but will be slower in <16 bits platforms as `int` is 16 bits minimum by standard. Also, if I used `uint8_t` it will be slower on >8 bits platforms as the compiler adds an `AND 0xFF` instruction to check overflow for each increment (my ARM7 compiler does that even on full speed optimization). `size_t` is also not an option since it can be bigger than the native integer size.

   Bad side (?) of this if an overflow is expected for 8 bits, it is not gonna happen. Programmer should check for overflow manually (as he/she should IMHO), which may result in buggy code if forgotten. Also, compiler (and even PC-Lint to my surprise) will not give any warning/issue if LOOP_COUNT "accidentally" set to a value bigger than 255 on >8 bits platforms, but the warning will be generated on an 8 bits platform, which will reduce portability and introduce bugs, but this can be avoided with `#if` checks.
2. Use least data types as much as possible if memory usage is of concern like in arrays or structures. For example:

   ```
   uint_least8_t array[100];
   ```

   It is the most portable and efficient way to declare arrays if memory usage is of concern. This type will give a byte array if byte access is possible on the platform, and give the smallest accessible width integer array otherwise. Also, least types can be used in structures if we have arrays of the structure.

   Least type can also suffer the problems fast types do, as width of variables can be changed on different platforms for both cases.
3. Avoid fixed width data types as much as possible as they may not even exist on some platforms, except hardware register access, communication protocol mapping, etc. where we need to know the exact bits of the variable. For example:

   ```
   typedef struct {
       uint8_t  flags;
       uint8_t  length;
       uint8_t  data[100];
       uint16_t crc;
   } __attribute__((packed)) package_t;
   ```

   Usually `__attribute__((packed))` (or something similar) should be used to ensure no padding will be inserted for these cases, as this can be a problem by itself.

Now, if my understanding is true, I think least data types are more likely to be used in arrays or structures, fast data types are more likely to be used for single variables and fixed data types are unlikely to be used in order to achieve maximum portability and efficiency. But typing "fast" and "least" every time is not encouraging. So, I think of a type set as follows:

```
    typedef [u]intN_t       os_[u|s]exactN_t;
    typedef [u]int_fastN_t  os_[u|s]N_t;
    /* I couldn't come up with a better name */
    typedef [u]int_leastN_t os_[u|s]minN_t;
    /* These may change */
    typedef uint_least8_t   os_byte_t;
    typedef uint_least16_t  os_word_t;
    /* ... */
```

- First and the important question is, is my understanding true?
- What would be the most portable AND efficient way to use C99 standard types and how would you declare them if it is not true?
- Does my type set makes sense or is it likely to produce buggy code?

Also, I would be pleased to know how and where you use C99 standard types.

Comment: Just to get this out of the way, is the application you are building the type of application where performance is so critical that these kinds of micro-optimizations are going to matter?

Comment: This looks like some sort of network or socket application. I really doubt that integer performance is gonna matter much here...

Comment: Where does "don't use fixed-width-types" rationalize? Your rationale for relying on packing a structure indicates you're planning on *sending* it on a wire or read/writing on its format in a file. Either of those is a far-worse move than relying on a `uint32_t` actually being 32-bits.

Comment: @Robert I want to build a generic framework, so it may be. But I'm curious of how it can be done even if performance is not so critical

Comment: @WhozCraig Fixed-width-types may not even exist on some platforms. So using least types is better if they solve the problem IMHO. Also packing a structure is just one example for fixed type usage, I couldn't come up with a better one.

Comment: If it helps, performance and portability tend to be conflicting goals. I'm not entirely sure exactly where on the curve you want to be.

Comment: @obareey I concur with you on least-types to be clear. It was not evident to me you were specifically referring to **Exact-Width** types per C99 §7.20.1.1 in your description. Either fast or least types are required per the standard and thus should be preferred. The structure packing line item is another issue, and one I avoid at all costs by simply not using them in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writing highly portable code is hard. Writing highly portable code that is optimal and works correctly is even harder.

For the majority of time, if it is feasible, I would suggest using basic types such as `int`, `char`, etc, rather than `uint8_t` or `uint8_fast_t`. The types `int` and `char` is guaranteed to exist. There is no doubt about that. Of course, SOMETIMES we need a specific behaviour from the code, and that will require a specific type - but that code will most likely break if the system doesn't support that exact type.

For your first example, it is extremely unlikely that you'll get better performance than using `int`, unless your code is designed to (also) run on 8-bit processors. On a 16-, 32- or 64-bit processor, the native size will be the fastest for loops (unsigned being slightly better on 64-bit machines, since it doesn't require sign extension).

In your second example, it really only matters if the array is large enough to warrant the space-saving over using either `char` or `int` or `short` or whatever makes sense for the content. On modern machines (including many embedded platforms and even when usign the stack) 400 bytes isn't really that much.

For your third example, obviously, for protocols, you will need to use types that match the protocol definition exactly, or things will go wrong. On platforms that doesn't support the correct type, this will have to be solved in some platform specific way - how you go about it will depend on exactly what the platform actually supports.

So, to answer your concrete questions:

- Seems like you understand the overall concept. But you also seem to
  be trying to push it further than it needs to be pushed, if that
  makes sense.
- Not applicable.
- Excessive use of "special type" variables is likely to:

  1. slow things down,
  2. potentially cause bugs, especially if it's not used consistently.

Remember also that performance is often a case of 90% of the time is taken by 10% of the code. Understanding where (under normal usage) your code spends its time is critical. Of course, when porting code to different systems and on different architectures, you may find that the performance bottleneck moves, based on the relationship between processor speed, size of caches and memory speed. A system with high processor speed, but (realtively) small caches can sometimes perform worse than a similar system with lower clock-speed and bigger caches, just as one example.

Comment: whaaaaat? uint8_fast_t specifically means "the fastest unsigned integer for this CPU which is at least 8 bits", unless your compiler is bugged/stupid, if "int" is the fastest (and is >=8 bits), uint8_fast_t will be an int.

Comment: So the benefit of using that, over plain `int`, aside from making you type more?

Comment: if you don't need more than 8 bits, and there is something smaller than int which is just as fast you'll use less memory, and if there is something faster than int, it will execute faster

Comment: and in arcs like x86, if you use int, you will dedicate an entire cpu register for this int (say EAX), but if you use int8, you might just dedicate AX or AL (which is 50% or 25% of EAX) for storing this int, and you can store several int8s in the same register, as we all know, memory is very slow compared to the CPU registers ~ can speed things up

Comment: Right, so if you write code that way, feel free to continue. I will continue following my advice. It is extremely rare to find that the compiler uses the same register for more than one thing, because on many of the x86 processors, there is a penalty for using two parts of the same register. Whilst registers are faster than memory, it's, in my 30-year experience, very rare that you save ANYTHING on optimising the size of a loop variable, for example. It may apply on 8- or 16-bit embedded systems, but for machines with megabytes of memory, it's usually completely different things that matter.